# SQL: Alert and recurrence on counter

Tags: sql

[image]

I want to calculate an alert with sql query.

The data collection is like below and I have 2 month history data and 4000 customers:

date collection: 02/11/2017
nb_reboot: 2
ref_custom: CCC123

I would like to list the customers (ref_custom) that exceeded the threshold (nb_reboot=3) during the last 3 days.

Comment: wich dbms are you using?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would also clarify what you want to do.

Comment: I edit the question and add image.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-Server:

```
select ref_custom
from your_table
where nb_reboot > MAX_REBOOT
      and date_collection >= dateadd(day, -3, getdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood your problem correctly.

For PostgreSQL,
I think you can use below query.

```
select ref_custom ,sum(nb_reboot) nb_reboot
from test_so
where date_collection>  current_date - interval '3' day
group by ref_custom
having sum(nb_reboot)>=3;
```

Attaching sqlfiddle screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answers but the query is not working. I add the sample (screenshot) and expected result .So the expected result should be custom1,custom2 because they reach the threshold the  last 3 days consecutively.@Tajinder@McNets:

Comment: I try the 2 following queries but it is not working :    select ref_custom
from Reboot
where nb_reboot > 3
      and CollectionTime >= dateadd(day, -3, getdate.I have an error  "the function does not exist.@McNets

Comment: What RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Heisql. Which one do you suggest to me?@Tajinder

Comment: I ' using now Mysql workbench and i still have the same error.   "UNCTION docsis.dateadd does not exist "@Tajinder@McNets